# Angular animation on model change

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm discovering angular and am quite impressed by this framework.

I'm digging into animation. It seems very powerful but I don't find something which seems easy.

I have a value which is binded in the scope. Let's say `<span>{{article.title}}</span>`. I want to put a animation on the background when the model is changing... How can I do that easily?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you looked into `ng-animate` ?

Comment: Yes, but nganimate seems perfekt for ngswitch, or change in a collection, or when a dom element is removed or added. But for an easy binding in the template?

Comment: Sorry I was reading articles about previous version... $animate.addClass seems to do what I'm looking for... I'll dig further later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.directive([ "$animate", function ($animate) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var oldVal = attrs.animateWhen;
        attrs.$observe('animateWhen', function (value) {
            if (value != oldVal) {
                $animate.addClass(element, attrs.animateClass);
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

In your html:

```
<span data-animate-when="{{ article.title }}" data-animate-class="aAnimationClassYouMakeOrUse">{{ article.title }}</span>
```

I have not tested it but the basic idea is like this.